# ¿como hago que todos los numeros de un array se resten?

Tags: python, array, lista

Hola me gustaria hacer algo asi me podeis ayudar ya que he estado buscando y no encuentro ninguna funcion que reste los elementos de una array

```
array1 = [1, 5, 2]
resta = restar elementos de array1 = 5 - 2 - 1
resta = 2
```

Comment: ¿Por qué en ese orden y no como vienen?

Comment: Puede ser cualquier orden eso no tiene importancia

Comment: `2 * array1[0] - sum(array1)`.

Comment: Gracias brother <3<3<3<3<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres restar desde el mayor número hasta el menor número, primero tendrías que ordenar de mayor a menor los elementos del arreglo, esto puedes hacerlo con el método **`sort(reverse=True)`**:

```
array1 = [1, 5, 2]
array1.sort(reverse=True)
print(array1)

# [5, 2, 1]
```

Ahora, a éste último resultado, podrías aplicar el método **`reduce()`** para restar los elementos del arreglo. Para ello, deberías importar el paquete `functools`, tu código sería así:

```
import functools

array1 = [1, 5, 2]
array1.sort(reverse=True)
print(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a - b, array1))

# 2
```

Enlaces:

> **sort():** *https://j2logo.com/python/ordenar-una-lista-en-python/*
>
> **reduce():** *https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/*

Comment: No necesitas ordenar para separar el mayor y usar reduce `2 * max(array1) - sum(array1)`

Comment: Sí, pero sería bueno para aplicar buenas prácticas del `sort()` y `reduce()`.